# MKPolygon covering pole

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'd like to create an `MKPolygon` with a portion that covers a pole.

Drawing a polygon around 0 N 0 E works as expected:

```
let coordinates = [
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20, longitude: 0),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 20),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -20, longitude: 0),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: -20),
]
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
```

[image: Shaded square around 0 N 0 E]

Attempting to draw a similar square around 90 S 0 E produces a straight line:

```
let coordinates = [
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -70, longitude: 0),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -70, longitude: 90),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -70, longitude: -180),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -70, longitude: -90),
]
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
```

[image: Straight line at 70 S]

It seems like the coordinates may be converted to map's projection before the path is drawn, although I'm not sure.

Setting `.mapType = .hybridFlyover` doesn't change much:

[image: Unfilled circle around pole]

What is the correct way to create an `MKPolygon` around the pole?

Comment: That map projection doesn’t really have a pole. It’s undefined due to the distortion/stretching at large latitudes. Have you tried it with the full-globe-view?

Comment: I get similar results; see the edit for a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I've just seen the same result when adding straight MKPolylines and MKGeodesicPolylines that run from pole to pole to a map in my own app. Seems to be a limitation to Apple's implementation but it's odd that I can still e.g. drop a pin at the pole without a problem.